# Можно ли узнать, когда и кем были установлено/удалено приложение в Windows?

Tags: windows

Содержаться ли где-то сведения об этом, например, в Системном журнале?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Какое-то определенное приложение? Чего вы этим хотите добиться?

Comment: Вообще да, сообщения от msiexec смотреть надо, но если журнал мелкий, а флуда много, скорее всего, они были стерты как слишком старые.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов. В списке установленных программ в панели управления есть даты. Если программу тупо скопировали, то это никак нельзя считать установкой, по крайней мере, если относительно этого нет дополнительной оговорки. Где в реестре эти даты хранятся?

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае нельзя. Создание файла с программой на диске, например, может затем сопровождаться подменой временнЫх меток файловой системы и т.п. В итоге никакой информации об истинном времени появления файла не будет, но установкой это вполне можно считать. Отдельные же случаи установки вполне могут оставлять достаточно информации для определения времени.

Comment: Да в реестр большинство инсталляторов прописывают дату...

Comment: В некоторых случаях: если есть инсталлятор и он что-то пишет в реестр.

Comment: Я и не имел ввиду простое копирование файла на диск. Я знаю, что в Панели управления есть список установленных приложений и я говорю именно об этих приложениях.